# Not able to run flutter project OU Notes. Assistance needed

Tags: flutter, dart

I am not able run this flutter please help me out. I am new to flutter. To see what's wrong please clone this project from below link and try to run this project on either android or web.
Gthub Link:
https://github.com/AbdulMalikDev/ounotes

[image]

**debug console output**

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Chrome in debug mode...
: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '?.' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
      WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
                     ^

: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
        WidgetsBinding.instance!.window,
                       ^

: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                   ^

: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                   ^

: Error: Undefined name 'OutlineButton'.
                OutlineButton.icon(
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
: Error: Undefined name 'OutlineButton'.
            OutlineButton.icon(
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addObserver(this);
                   ^
: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.

- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
    final window = WidgetsBinding.instance!.window;
                                  ^

: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.removeObserver(this);
                   ^

: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
      data: MediaQueryData.fromWindow(WidgetsBinding.instance!.window),
                                                     ^
: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.

- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addObserver(this);
                   ^

: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.removeObserver(this);
                   ^

: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.
- 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
        SchedulerBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                         ^

: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.
- 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
      SchedulerBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                       ^

: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.
- 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
      SchedulerBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                       ^

: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.
- 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
    SchedulerBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback(
                     ^

: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '?.' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.
- 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
    SchedulerBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) => onReady());
                     ^

: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '?.' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.
- 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
    SchedulerBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) => onReady());
                     ^

: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addObserver(this);
                   ^

: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').

    WidgetsBinding.instance!.removeObserver(this);
                   ^
: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
      WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                     ^

: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addObserver(this);
                   ^

: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.removeObserver(this);

                   ^
: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
          bottom: WidgetsBinding.instance!.window.viewInsets.bottom /
                                 ^

: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
              WidgetsBinding.instance!.window.devicePixelRatio),
                             ^
: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '?.' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
    WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                   ^

: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.removeObserver(this);
                   ^

: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addObserver(this);
                   ^

: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((duration) {
                   ^

: Error: No named parameter with the name 'maxLengthEnforced'.
        maxLengthEnforced: widget.textFieldConfiguration.maxLengthEnforced,
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  const TextField({

        ^^^^^^^^^
: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.removeObserver(this);
                   ^

: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addObserver(this);
                   ^

: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((duration) {
                   ^

: Error: No named parameter with the name 'maxLengthEnforced'.
        maxLengthEnforced: widget.textFieldConfiguration.maxLengthEnforced,
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  const CupertinoTextField({
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '?.' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
    WidgetsBinding.instance?.addObserver(this);
                   ^

: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '?.' has type 'ImageCache' which excludes null.
- 'ImageCache' is from 'package:flutter/src/painting/image_cache.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_cache.dart').
    imageCache?.clear();
    ^

: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '?.' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
    WidgetsBinding.instance?.removeObserver(this);
                   ^

: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '?.' has type 'ImageCache' which excludes null.
- 'ImageCache' is from 'package:flutter/src/painting/image_cache.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_cache.dart').
    imageCache?.clear();
    ^

: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '?.' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
                          WidgetsBinding.instance?.window.viewInsets.bottom !=
                                         ^

: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
                                WidgetsBinding.instance!.window.viewInsets,
                                               ^
: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.

- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
                                    .instance!.window.devicePixelRatio)
                                     ^

: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '?.' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
      WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((Duration timeStamp) {
                     ^

: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '?.' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
            WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((Duration timeStamp) {

                           ^
: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '?.' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
          WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((Duration timeStamp) {
                         ^

: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '?.' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
      WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((Duration timeStamp) {
                     ^

: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '?.' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
          WidgetsBinding.instance

                         ^
: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '?.' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
      WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((Duration timeStamp) {
                     ^

: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '?.' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
        WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((Duration timeStamp) {

                       ^
: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                   ^

: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.
- 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
    SchedulerBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
                     ^

: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'ImageCache' which excludes null.
- 'ImageCache' is from 'package:flutter/src/painting/image_cache.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_cache.dart').
    imageCache!.clear();
    ^

: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'ImageCache' which excludes null.
- 'ImageCache' is from 'package:flutter/src/painting/image_cache.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_cache.dart').
    imageCache!.clear();
    ^

: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '?.' has type 'PaintingBinding' which excludes null.
- 'PaintingBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/painting/binding.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/binding.dart').
    PaintingBinding.instance?.imageCache?.clear();
                    ^

: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '?.' has type 'PaintingBinding' which excludes null.
- 'PaintingBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/painting/binding.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/binding.dart').
    PaintingBinding.instance?.imageCache?.clearLiveImages();
                    ^
: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '?.' has type 'PaintingBinding' which excludes null.
- 'PaintingBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/painting/binding.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/binding.dart').
      PaintingBinding.instance?.imageCache?.clear();
                      ^

: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '?.' has type 'PaintingBinding' which excludes null.
- 'PaintingBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/painting/binding.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/binding.dart').
      PaintingBinding.instance?.imageCache?.clearLiveImages();
                      ^
: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '?.' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
      WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((Duration timeStamp) {
                     ^

: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.
- 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
        SchedulerBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                         ^
: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '?.' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.

- 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
          SchedulerBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) => _refresh());
                           ^

: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.
- 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
        SchedulerBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                         ^
: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.

- 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
          SchedulerBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) => _refresh());
                           ^

: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.
- 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
        SchedulerBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                         ^
: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.

- 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
          SchedulerBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) => _refresh());
                           ^

: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.
- 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
        SchedulerBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                         ^

: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.
- 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
          SchedulerBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) => _refresh());
                           ^

: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '?.' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
      WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((Duration timeStamp) {
                     ^

: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '?.' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
    WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((Duration timeStamp) {
                   ^

: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.
- 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
            SchedulerBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback(
                             ^

Failed to compile application.
Exited (sigterm)
```

Comment: Provide necessary code to reproduce the error

Answer (score 0):

We can now **DISCARD THE WARNING** and wait until the authors of these packages deal with the new changes in flutter 3 to solve the problem and update their packages. The developers of the packages are now catching up on these changes and there should be new versions of the affected packages soon.

Example of a package with this issue:

> These warnings should not be breaking anything (just causing log spam,
> for which we apologize; we plan to fix that in the next release, we
> didn't realize how big of an issue it would be). If your app no longer
> works, that is unlikely to be related to this issue

reference:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/103561#issuecomment-1126416045